# How to get details of a JSON Server response parsed into list/dictionary in Python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, code-conversion

I am new to Python. I have been trying to parse the response sent as parameter in a function.

I have been trying to convert a function from Perl to Python.

The Perl block looks something like this:

```
sub fetchId_byusername
{
     my ($self,$resString,$name) =@_;
     my $my_id;
     my @arr = @{$json->allow_nonref->utf8->decode($resString)};
     foreach(@arr)
     {
          my %hash = %{$_};
          foreach my $keys (keys %hash)
          {
               $my_id = $hash{id} if($hash{name} eq $name);
          }
     }
     print "Fetched Id is : $my_id\n";
     return $my_id;
```

The part where JSON data is being parsed is troubling me. How do i write this in python3.

I tried something like

```
    def fetchID_byUsername(self, resString, name):
        arr = []
        user_id = 0
        arr = resString.content.decode('utf-8', errors="replace")
        for item in arr:
            temp_hash = {}
            temp_hash = item
            for index in temp_hash.keys():
                if temp_hash[name] == name:
                    user_id = temp_hash[id]
        print("Fetched  ID is: {}".format(user_id))
        return user_id
```

Now I am not sure, if this is the right way to do it.

The json inputs are something like:

```
[{"id":12345,"name":"11","email":"11@test.com","groups":[{"id":6967,"name":"Test1"},{"id":123456,"name":"E1"}],"department":{"id":3863,"name":"Department1"},"comments":"111","adminUser":false},{"id":123457,"name":"1234567","email":"1234567@test.com","groups":[{"id":1657,"name":"mytest"},{"id":58881,"name":"Service Admin"}],"department":{"id":182,"name":"Service Admin"},"comments":"12345000","adminUser":true}]
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You might want to give more information about where you are currently in your programming process. A snippet of your code, or an error message would be helpful. It'll give us an idea of how to help you, rather than just saying that you're trying to parse the response.

Comment: You got the response from server now you want to parse. what client you are using?

Comment: @iwillnot I have added the information for the same. The question got submitted before completion accidentally.

Comment: @YugandharChaudhari I have added the information for the same. The question got submitted before completion accidentally.

Comment: `resString` is it json formatted string?

Comment: @YugandharChaudhari It seems that the complete response as shown above is feeded into this `resString` variable, would be later parsed.

Comment: so what this function does? Is it matching name with the records and returning id of found record?

Comment: @YugandharChaudhari Yes, it receives a `name` to match and return the respective `id` for the corresponding value of  `name`

Comment: I will just add that the _method could be a function_. There is no use of self.

Comment: @PedroRodrigues actually the function is a part of class, hence i used self in it. You can ignore it for now.

Comment: A function part of a class is called a _method_ (there various kinds of methods, `instance`, `class`, `static`). But the method makes no use of `self`, so it can be a function or a static method (a static method is essentially a function stuck in a class; for namespace conflicts maybe reasonable, loosely reasonable). But makes no sense as an instance method. I know it is not the end of the world, but you mention beeing new to python. And that is part of good python code. You may read more at https://docs.quantifiedcode.com/python-anti-patterns/correctness/method_could_be_a_function.html

Comment: @PedroRodrigues Thanks for the info, I didn't knew about it. As far as the problem is concerned, can you suggest a solution for it?..

Comment: I'm not sure what `resValue` actually is. What type. As for parsing json, python has a json module in the std lib. `import json`, not sure how it will work out with that `resValue`.

Answer (score 0):

Your json input should be valid python I changed `false` to `False` and `true` to `True`. If it is json formatted string you can do

```
import json
data=json.loads(json_formatted_string_here) #data will be python dictionary herer
```

And tried like this it just iterates and when match found returns id

```
data=[{"id":12345,"name":"11","email":"11@test.com","groups":[{"id":6967,"name":"Test1"},{"id":123456,"name":"E1"}],"department":{"id":3863,"name":"Department1"},"comments":"111","adminUser":False},{"id":123457,"name":"1234567","email":"1234567@test.com","groups":[{"id":1657,"name":"mytest"},{"id":58881,"name":"Service Admin"}],"department":{"id":182,"name":"Service Admin"},"comments":"12345000","adminUser":True}]

def fetch_id_by_name(list_records,name):
    for record in list_records:
        if record["name"] == name:
            return record["id"]

print(fetch_id_by_name(data,"11"))
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all import the the json library and use json.loads() like:

```
import json

x = json.loads(json_feed) #This converts the json feed to a python dictionary
print(x["key"]) #values to "key"
```